# jQuery Floating Header Is Laggy

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, floating

Environment:
Rails 3.1rc5 with jQuery, ubuntu 11.04, Google Chrome (13), Mozilla Firefox (6.0)

I am working on a project that has a pretty limited, in-office rollout - so I can safely say that we will always have this running in the latest version of Firefox; we can do whatever crazy js, css3, or html5 we want.

The project is meant to mimic an application, with a side bar (for actions) and a pane in the middle with a list of orders that scolls (both horizontally and vertically), while the body does not scroll.

The middle pane has a header above the orders which we need to float down the page as the user scrolls. We can't use position:fixed because we need to scroll horizontally as well as vertically (there are more fields than screen real estate). I've got it working but it's laggy in Chrome and very laggy in Firefox - the header doesn't seem to actually move until the user stops scrolling.

Since this is a sort of complicated layout, I've tried to recreate it in jsfiddle, however I can't get it to actually make the scrolling on the middle pane work. It will at least give a better idea of what I am trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/d3vkit/8E786/

Here is the coffeescript I am using:

```
jQuery ->
  order_headings_list = $("#order_headings_list")
  orders_list = $("#orders_list")

  orders_list.scroll ->
    topOffset = orders_list.scrollTop() + "px"
    order_headings_list.css('top', topOffset)
```

Here is the javascript that produces:

```
orders_list.scroll(function() {
  var leftOffset, topOffset;
  topOffset = orders_list.scrollTop() + "px";
  order_headings_list.css('top', topOffset);
});
```

My only idea is that it's because I am moving a bunch of list items over a lot of list items, perhaps it's just too much.

Am I doing this floating header correctly? Any pointers to tighten things up? (And why isn't my fiddle showing the overflow scrolling?)

## UPDATE

I have worked a bit more on the jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/d3vkit/8E786/) and got the header moving, showing the lag that happens. Seems to me that you scroll, and it updates the css, but not quick enough, so it seems jumpy. How can I fix this?

Comment: why are you wrapping stuff in a jquery function? Also I am really not sure what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I was under the impression that I had to do that to have it run on document load - I am very new to coffeescript, and actually use prototype more than jquery, so maybe this isn't needed?
I am trying to make a vertically floating header that stays put on horizontal scroll, and moves with a scrolling div, but it's not fluid.

Answer (score 0):

why not just use position fixed

http://jsfiddle.net/pnAvm/

Comment: Because I need to be able to scroll horizontally as well as vertically, but on horizontal scroll, a fixed position element moves along with the scroll. I am considering trying to just read the size of the monitor with js and changing the size of the fields to fit the width, so there is no horiz scroll, but that might complicate things down the line should we add more fields (it'll get mighty cramped).